# REST resource modelling for decision based outcome

Tags: java, json, rest, post, http-post

We have 2 systems A and B. System A is doing some manual review task and one this review task is completed, system A is supposed to share the review result outcome with system B. System B is not supposed to poll system A for review result.

While designing the API for this ask, we built a resource which looks like following

POST /review-xyz-result/

```
{
 "var1": "string",
 "var2": "string",
 "var3": "string",
 "reviewDecision": "X, Y, Z"
}
```

When the outcome is Y, var 1 , var2 and var 3 will be populated. For decision X and Z , variables will be empty.The review result can only have one decision ie. either X or Y or Z.

What is the best way to model such a resource.?

Some opinions in our development group said that lets break the single API in to 3 endpoint one for each decision. Someway, I do not feel that is the right way to do. System A would need to put logic at their end to call the right endpoint and populate the dependent variables.

So my first question is, can a resource have optional attributes?

For the case under consideration, why separate endpoints would make any sense?

Comment: Do you want call from A the API of B? So you're asking for an URL with optinal params for system B?

Comment: yes. System B is going to publish a post endpoint for system A.

Answer (score 0):

My Perspective: There is no hard Rule while designing REST api(single URL for all scenarios or separate URL for scenario based). Mostly scenario based URL's are not much suggested if it is not really required, because it will end up with more URL's if your business scenarios increased in future.

If your functionality of X,Y,Z is totally different irrespective of scenarios then try it for different URL's. If functionality is same only the reviewDecision parameter is different, then i suggest you to go with path param( `/host/controller/{reviewDecision}/`) in single URL then add the other content in body.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a little bit of HATEOAS and split the `decision` from the `vars`.

1. POST on `/review-xyz-result` and you get:

```
{
"reviewDecision":"X" (OR) "Z",
"variables-href":""
}
```

OR

```
{
"reviewDecision":"Y",
"variables-href":"/review-xyz-result/{idOfResource}" OR
"variables-href":"/review-xyz-result/var"
}
```

And then you call POST on `/review-xyz-result/{idOfResource}` OR etc